# In Commerce 2, is it possible to have the product variation automatically created during product creation?

Tags: commerce

We have a Commerce 2 store whose products will always only have one variation.

The current workflow to create a new product **and** its variation is a bit complicated for the user's who will be entering in the product data.

Out of the box you have to click the 'create variation' button after entering in the variation information. There is then additional option buttons to Edit, Remove, or Duplicate the variation.

We'd like to streamline this process and have the single variation created automatically so all the user needs to do is enter a price during the product creation and not have to click any additional buttons.

I was hoping there was a module available that would facilitate this functionality but I was unable to find one.

If not module exists, what would be the best way to achieve this?

Perhaps a custom 'product' form that then creates the Commerce Product programmatically when the form is submitted? I don't really like this idea because I would also have to consider editing the product as well.

Would some custom code be able to tweak the existing workflow to hide the variation info and create it automatically? Perhaps getting the price from a custom price field added to the product entity?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update to Commerce 2.10.

Then, edit your product type and uncheck the *Allow each product to have multiple variations* checkbox. This will give you a *Product information* fieldset on the product add/edit form with the variation fields.

Comment: Wow! What a timely updated to Commerce. Thank you.